# Semi-Conjugacy and the preservation of wandering intervals

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, circles, rotations

This is mostly a checking of my understanding. Currently I am working through the proof of Denjoy's Theorem in Katok and Hasselblatt's *Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems,* and specifically Lemma 12.1.2 (p. 402).

What this lemma does is it establishes a (finite) sequence of non-intersecting intervals from the orbit of a point by homeomorphism on the circle with irrational rotation number. We have already proven that such a homeomorphism is semi-conjugate to a rotation by this rotation number. K&H construct these intervals for the rotation, and claim that this automatically gives us the intervals for the homeomorphism because, "the claim only involves the ordering of the orbit... Since f is either conjugate or semiconjugate to an irrational rotation, we can thus assume f itself is an irrational rotation."

I wanted to check this, but the only way I could get this result was by the fact that the surjective continuous map we constructed as the semi-conjugacy between the rotation and the homeomorphism was increasing (only strictly in the case of full conjugacy, of course). In this case it was easy, because if $f$ is the homeomorphism, $r$ is the rotation, and $h$ is continuous surjection satisfying $h\circ f = r \circ h$, then the images of the orbit intervals for $f$ under $h$ correspond exactly to (and do not exceed, as is possible without monotonicity) the intervals formed by the orbit of a point under $r$. However, K&H do not mention the monotonicty, and seem to imply that this relation follows directly from the semi-conjugacy.

I guess the thing I'd worry about is if my semi-conjugacy were instead, say, $x^3 + x^2$, which is surjective and continuous but has a little "wiggle" in the middle, and if the two points in an $f$ orbit, call them $y_i,y_j,$ lie on the wiggle you can get it such that $(x_i,x_j) = (h(y_i),h(y,j)) \subset h((y_i,y_j)),$ where $x_i,x_j$ are part of the orbit of the rotation which we found did what we desired. This $h^{-1}((x_i,x_j)) \subset h^{-1}(h((y_i,y_j)))),$ which also contains $(y_i,y_j),$ and I can't see any good way to get $(y_i,y_j)$ inside of $h^{-1}((x_i,x_j))$ to set up the empty intersection with another interval. Of course, this is not a problem with the monotonic map.

More broadly, I want to make sure that this ordering of orbits is not something generally preserved/fully reversed by semi-conjugacy, as implied by K&H, but a special case of this particular semi-conjugacy. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the Poincaré Classification, so Theorem 11.2.7, they state that the homeomorphism $f$ with irrational rotation number is semiconjugate to the Rotation $R_\tau$ via a noninvertible, continuous and monotone map $h: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$.

Not sure if this late answer helps you, but I guess that's what you're looking for.